# Using pandas styling on the command line

Tags: python, pandas

I've recently come across pandas new [styling interface](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/style.html) which looks like you can do a lot of neat things, [like](https://pbpython.com/styling-pandas.html):

```
(monthly_sales.style
 .format(format_dict)
 .background_gradient(subset=['sum'], cmap='BuGn'))
```

[image]

Most of my work happens in a command line however. Is there a way to visualize the output from this in a way that works in bash or tcsh?

Comment: Pandas styling is generally designed for HTML output, so in theory one option would be to use `df.to_html` and have the command line pop the table up in a browser window

Comment: @G.Anderson ah, I was hoping that there was an option to reduce this down to something the shell could display. If not, then maybe I need to write a module for it!

Comment: From what I can tell, based on the docs the styling only  "return[s] like-indexed DataFrames or Series with CSS "attribute: value" pairs" so you can use jupyter notebooks in place of CLI, or find a CLI that supports css, I suppose?